# map string to entity for using with generic method

Tags: c#, generics, nhibernate

if I have the following classes:

```
class Fruit {}
class Apple : Fruit {}
class Orange : Fruit {}
```

and I have method:

```
public List<Fruit> getFruit<T>() where T : Fruit {

 List<Fruit> fruitList = new List<Fruit>();
 return fruitList.AddRange(session.QueryOver<T>().List());

}
```

Is it possible to have a dictionary that maps a string to a type that can be passed to this generic method so I can query over the right table?

for example:

```
Dictionary<string, type> typeMapper = new Dictionary<string, type>()
{
 {"Apple", AppleType??}
};

var myType = typeMapper["Apple"];
List<Fruit> fruitList = getFruit<myType>();
```

Comment: generic types in c# must be known at compile time. You can't use <typeof(mytype)> because it's not a compiler time operation. From MSDN.com  -  "The type argument can be any type recognized by the compiler."... (and it's not recognized if you use run-time operation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using Dictionary to store delegates ?

```
    Dictionary<string, Func<List<Fruit>>> typeMapper = new Dictionary<string, Func<List<Fruit>>>()
    {
        {"Apple", () => { return getFruit<Apple>(); } },
        {"Orange", () => { return getFruit<Orange>(); } }
    };

    List<Fruit> fruitList = typeMapper["Apple"]();
```

Comment: This is the answer I've been waiting for!

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection to call a generic method with a `Type`

```
[Fact]
public void Test_WithTypesAndReflection_Succeeds()
{
    var typeMapper = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
    {
        { "Apple", typeof(Apple) },
        { "Orange", typeof(Orange) }
    };

    var method = (
        from m in this.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        where m.Name == "GetFruit"
        where m.GetParameters().Count() == 0
        select m).Single();

    var result = (IEnumerable<Fruit>)method
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeMapper["Apple"])
        .Invoke(this, null);
}

private IEnumerable<Fruit> GetFruit<T>() where T : Fruit
{
    return Enumerable.Empty<T>().Cast<Fruit>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create instances of unknown type using Reflection. This can be done using `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Apple))` e g.
Having said this you won´t need generics at all:

```
Dictionary<string, Type> typeMapper = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
{
    {"Apple", typeof(Apple)}
};

var myType = typeMapper["Apple"];
var apple = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

EDIT: However this method is not typesafe, so all you get is an `object` instead of your concrete type. You may cast the result to `Fruit` however and add it to the list:

```
fruitList.Add((Fruit) apple);
```