# Accepting multiple similar entities in a Method - Elegant solution

Tags: c#, .net

I have two data entities, which are almost similar, design is something like:

```
public Class Entity1 : Base
{
  public int layerId;

  public List<int> Groups;
}
```

Difference is `Entity1` has an extra collection of `integer Groups`

```
public Class Entity2 : Base
{
  public int layerId;
}
```

These entities are filled as an input from UI using Json, I need to pass them to a processing method, which gives the same Output entity. Method has a logic to handle if `List<int> Groups is null`, I need to create a method which is capable of handling each of the input in an elegant manner. I cannot just use only `Entity1`, since they are two different functional inputs for different business process, so using `Entity1` as direct replacement would be a mis-representation

Instead of creating overload of the function, I can think of following options:

1. Use object type as input and typecast in the function internally
2. I think we can similarly use dynamic types, but solution will be similar as above, it will not be a clean solution in either case, along with the `switch-case` mess.

What I am currently doing is processing method is like this:

```
public OuputEntity ProcessMethod(Entity 1)
{
  // Data Processing
}
```

I have created a constructor of `Entity1`, that takes `Entity2` as Input.

Any suggestion to create an elegant solution, which can have multiple such entities. May be using generic, where we use a Func delegate to create a common type out of two or more entities, which is almost similar to what I have currently done. Something like:

```
Func<T,Entity1>
```

Thus use `Entity1` output for further processing in the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to create a method which is capable of handling each of the input in an elegant manner

Create an `Interface`, or a contract so to speak, where each entity adheres to the particular design. That way common functionality can be processed in a similar manner. Subsequently each difference is expressed in other interfaces and testing for that interface sis done and the differences handled as such.

> May be using generic,

Generic types can be tested against interfaces and a *clean* method of operations hence follows suit.

For example say we have two entities that both have `Name` properties as string, but one has an `Order` property. So we define the common interface

```
public interface IName
{
   string Name { get; set; }
   string FullName { get;  }
}

public interface IOrder
{
   decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

So once we have our two entities of `EntityName` and `EntityOrder` we can add the interfaces to them, usually using the `Partial` class definition such as when EF creates them on the fly:

```
public partial class EntityName : IName
{
  // Nothing to do EntityName already defines public string Name { get; set; }

  public string FullName { get { return "Person: " +  Name; }}
}


public partial class EntityOrder : IName, IOrder
{
  // Nothing to do Entity Order already defines public string Name { get; set; }
  // and Amount.

  public string FullName { get { return "Order: " + Name; } }
}
```

Then we can process each of them together in the same method

```
public void Process(IName entity)
{
     LogOperation( entity.FullName );

   // If we have an order process it uniquely
   var order = entity as IOrder;

   if (order != null)
   {
      LogOperation( "Order: " + order.Amount.ToString() );
   }

}
```

Generic  methods can enforce an interface(s) such as:

```
public void Process<T>(T entity) where T : IName
{
   // Same as before but we are ensured that only elements of IName 
   // are used as enforced by the compiler.
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple example, not too clear where introducing Interface in this case would help. What are the methods we are looking forward in the Interface

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I have provided one. See [Interface Based Development](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_interrfaces03052006095933AM/csharp_interrfaces.aspx?ArticleID=cd6a6952-530a-4250-a6d7-54717ef3b345) as a further reading.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The methods and properties are unique to the process which needs them and the interface will *enforce* that uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information, this will be a good implementation. As of now it would be lot of effort to make this kind of change, since at some point of time we have to come down to a concrete class for processing, which would require an if-else or switch-case, but would be a good change for the future

Answer (score 1):

Just create generic method that will do this work for you:

```
List<OuputEntity> MyMethod<T>(T value) where T : Base 
// adding this constraint ensures that T is of type that is derived from Base type
{
   List<OutputEntity> result = new List<OutputEntity>();
   // some processing logic here like ...
   return result;
}

var resultForEntity1 = MyMethod<Entity1>();
var resultForEntity2 = MyMethod<Entity2>();
```

P.S. check my answer for this question as you may find it useful too:

[map string to entity for using with generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378105/map-string-to-entity-for-using-with-generic-method/31378634?noredirect=1#comment50748039_31378634)

Comment: Though in my case,  I would prefer input to the method as Func<T,Entity1> value instead if T value

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to implement an `interface` or an `abstract` class.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d(v=vs.71).aspx)

> If you anticipate creating multiple versions of your component, create
>   an abstract class. Abstract classes provide a simple and easy way to
>   version your components. By updating the base class, all inheriting
>   classes are automatically updated with the change. Interfaces, on the
>   other hand, cannot be changed once created. If a new version of an
>   interface is required, you must create a whole new interface.
>
> If the functionality you are creating will be useful across a wide range of
>   disparate objects, use an interface. Abstract classes should be used
>   primarily for objects that are closely related, whereas interfaces are
>   best suited for providing common functionality to unrelated classes.
>
> If you are designing small, concise bits of functionality, use
>   interfaces. If you are designing large functional units, use an
>   abstract class.
>
> If you want to provide common, implemented
>   functionality among all implementations of your component, use an
>   abstract class. Abstract classes allow you to partially implement your
>   class, whereas interfaces contain no implementation for any members.

**Abstract Class Example**

`Cat` and `Dog` can both inherit from `abstract` class `Animal`, and this abstract base class will implement a method `void Breathe()` which all animals will thus do in exactly the same fashion. (You might make this method `virtual` so that you can `override` it for certain animals, like `Fish`, which does not breath the same as most animals).

**Interface Example**

All animals can be fed, so you'll create an `interface` called `IFeedable` and have `Animal` implement that. Only `Dog` and `Horse` are nice enough though to implement `ILikeable` - You'll not implement this on the base class, since this does not apply to `Cat`.